# parsing date with simpledateformat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a column in oracle db with following data type

```
data type = TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

I exported it to CSV and then parsing the CSV using Java code.

Sample date: `10-JAN-14 12.48.00.000000000 AM`

Simple date format used to parse date: `dd-MMM-yy K.mm.ss.000000000 a`

The problem is the above date gets converted to `Fri Jan 10 12:48:00 PST 2014`

It gets converted to afternoon `12.48` (it was  supposed to be `00.48`).

EDIT:
If i use dd-MMM-yy K.hh.ss.000000000 a`or dd-MMM-yy K.mm.h.000000000 a` i get
Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 PST 2014, which is also wrong

Is there any thing wrong?

Comment: whats your JVM and Oracle time zone ?

Comment: PST , but that should not matter as i am reading data in csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your date string has `"AM/PM"` and your hour has range of `01-12` then you should use `h` to parse the hour

You can try `dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.000000000 a` as input format. If you see the documentation (`SimpleDateFormat`) of `K`, its range is `0-11`, hence the parsing fails.

Comment: dd-MMM-yy K.hh.ss.000000000 is a wrong pattern, K and h represents hours, and you should use only one of them

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you are using "K"? because the java documentation says that the capitak K values are between (0-11) so I wouldn't now how are you getting a 12.
Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: yes.But my csv file has value 10-JAN-14 12.48.00.000000000 AM

Answer (score -2):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

I'd sugest using Locale.getDefault() or any other value.

Comment: OK, put the pattern you need, e.g. "mm:ss.0000" or what you need, but IMO it should work. Thanks for the downvote, think was innecesary.

Comment: btw i didn't downvote .. It throws a runtime exception : Unparseable date: "10-JAN-14 12.48.00.000000000 AM"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)

Comment: Since you have the timestamp may be you can use new Date(timestamp) and then format it. But if you have the DB server in diferent timezone there will be some mess (that happens to me). And I don't know how oracle gives you the timestamp (never liked it).